# How can I replace first 5 characters of a string with new another string and padding in javascript?

Tags: javascript

if I have a string that needs to replace the first 5 character with a new string and with padding with 0s, what's the best way to do it?

ex:

```
const str1="jsdf532903043900934";
const str2= "21";


\\replace str1 with str2 "21" plus 3 zeros on the right
\\new string should be 2100032903043900934
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the substrings after index 5.

```js
const str1="jsdf532903043900934";
const str2= "21";

const newStr = str2 + "000" + str1.substr(5)
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str1 = "jsdf532903043900934";
const str2 = "21";

const result = replace(str1, str2, "5");
console.log(result);

function replace(str1, str2, length) {
  const pattern = new RegExp(`^.{${length}}`);
  return str1.replace(pattern, str2.padEnd(length, '0'));
}
```

I made this example accept a `length` parameter so it would be easier to change the length if necessary. If that isn't needed, you could remove it and change the expression to `^.{5}` and the second parameter to `replace` with `str2.padEnd(5, '0')`.

This regular expression matches the start of the string using `^` then matches any character using the `.` exactly `length` times using the `length` parmeter inserted inside curly braces.

Comment: This is definitely solvable without using regular expressions. William Wang's solution is simpler, although I do like the `padEnd` method for ensuring `str2` is at least 5 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using padStart and substr

```js
const str1="jsdf532903043900934";
const str2= "21234";

console.log(str2 + str1.substr(5).padStart(str1.length - str2.length,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly add 0 at the end of the string to prepend until you reach the desired length:

```
const str1="jsdf532903043900934";
const str2= "21";
var newString = str2;
for (let i = str2.length; i < 5; i++) newString += "0";
var output = newString + str1.substring(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using something like `slice()`, since `substr()` is now deprecated.

```
const str1 = "jsdf532903043900934"
const str2 = "21"
const str3 = str2 + "000" + str1.slice(2)
```

Comment: If they want similar behavior they should use `substring`.